# SCP file from A via B to localhost

Tags: linux, scp

I have a file on a server I would like to copy to my localhost. I can access the file from my localhost via:

```
ssh richard@B -t ssh richard@A
```

then

```
richard@A$ sudo bash (with password)
```

then here is the file

```
root@A$ /home/jboss/.m2/maven-repo.tar.gz
```

I am trying to copy a file from server `A` via server `B` to my localhost.  I have  tried a number of things, but they seem to fail with permission denied error.  I think this is because to access the file,  you need to be a super user (I do have the su password).

For example, if I try copy the file from `A` to `B`:

```
root@A$ scp /home/jboss/.m2/maven-repo.tar.gz richard@B: /home/richard/
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, why do you need to copy it to your local host from A via B? Why not just copy it from A directly to your local host? As far as the error message is concerned, it isn't possible to copy the from A to B because the former doesn't have access to the latter via SSH with a public key and/or root login via SSH isn't allowed on the latter.

Comment: I don't fully understand this because it's devops is not really my area of expertise, but I think there is a firewall on `A` that blocks public access, so only `B` can access `A`.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host

Comment: hi Gerald, thanks for the comment. I actually saw that post before I posted mine and tried all the suggestions as best I could (e.g. `oProxyJump`, `-3`, etc.) but couldn't get any to work.  I think it is because i can only ssh to a server as `richard` because that's what my access cert is, but need `root` to access the file (it is effectively missing the `sudo bash` cmd). So I get a permission denied error.   I think the suggestions in that  post work, if the ssh user is the root user.

Comment: I think `Rsync` my be the solution: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories

Comment: Often when a source file is only accessible by `root` and you can't log in directly as root, it is easiest to **first copy the file** to a location that can be accessed directly by the user doing the scp/sftp; for example /tmp/ or the home directory of that user. Then **transfer the copy** (and remove it afterwards).  Or vice versa, when the user doing the transfer can't write directly to the remote destination, also first upload the file to the server in a location you can write to, then log in as root and move the file to the correct final destination (and set the correct owner and perms)